# How to sum values from lots that have parent/child relationships?

Tags: sql

I have a situation where there is a table that holds parent and child lot that holds qty values for each container.

| Lot | Yield | Scrap | Date | Lot_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 1 | 01/01/21 | P |
| A-1 | 5 | 1 | 01/01/21 | C |
| A-2 | 5 | 1 | 01/01/21 | C |
| B | 5 | 1 | 01/01/21 | P |
| B-1 | 5 | 1 | 01/01/21 | C |
| B-2 | 5 | 1 | 01/02/21 | C |
| B-3 | 5 | 1 | 01/02/21 | C |
| B-5 | 5 | 1 | 01/06/21 | C |
| B-6 | 5 | 1 | 01/06/21 | C |
| A-1 | 5 | 1 | 01/10 /21 | C |
| A-2 | 5 | 1 | 01/10/21 | C |

Now I have a requirement where I have to sum the qty values for parent and child lots by date. SO in the end the output looks like this:

| Lot | Yield | Scrap | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 3 | 01/01/21 |
| B | 10 | 2 | 01/01/21 |
| B | 10 | 2 | 01/02/21 |
| B | 10 | 2 | 01/06/21 |
| A | 10 | 2 | 01/10/21 |

Ideally, we need to aggregate Containers by date and sum their yield and scrap values.

Hopefully this makes sense, and I appreciate your help

Comment: Please explain the logic for knowing the parent for a lot.  Is it as simple as the first character?  And tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query you would use, at least in SQL Server/T-SQL:

```
select left(Lot, 1), sum(Yield), sum(Scrap), Date 
from tbl_LotsExampleTable
group by left(Lot, 1), Date
```

That should produce the result table as you've requested. Ideally, something like child lots would be housed in a separate table, but this will work as long as the table's naming conventions as per above with a single letter denoting the lot. If that will change, then that specific part of the query will need to be changed from

```
left(Lot, 1)
```

to something else. Also, if the left() function is not available with what you're working with, the alternative would be

```
substring(Lot, 1, 1)
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!